# Issues rendering in IE

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm hoping that you may be able to help with some issues I'm having with a simple site in IE 8. Essentially everything appears to render and flow correctly in every other browser, but in IE the width of one of the divs becomes much smaller than it should be, and content is pushed down out of the desired flow. Here is a link to the site- http://www.fshtnkdesign.com/step-1/

It's currently a wordpress installation using Contact Form 7 and a Multi-Step Form plugin to achieve the desired result. Any help or assistance would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks for your time and wisdom.

Comment: Start by fixing your broken HTML: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.fshtnkdesign.com/step-1/ You seem to have included a full HTML document into another here, which is of course nonsense.

Comment: I've managed to bring it down to one error (related to Contact Form 7), but it didn't impact how it renders in IE. Thanks for pointing that out, I should have worked that out before I posted. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block for css class="content" div inside id="two" div

Comment: Thanks for the reply – I tried this, but it didn't work?